# ActiveRecord find with include against table with records that might not be there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

Here's my situation. I have a set of lists of words. Some words can appear in more than one list. For each word/list combination, I **might** have an example sentence.

Words

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
  has_many :sample_sentences
end
```

Lists

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :words
  has_many :sample_sentences
end
```

Sample Sentences

```
class SampleSentence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :word
  belongs_to :list
end
```

... and to support HABTM, I have a join table.

Everything works just fine **except** this:

Using eager loading, I would like to grab all words in a particular list **and** the sample sentences for that word for that particular list.

I have tried many variations with scopes, wheres, etc.

Most variations look something like this (testing in IRB)

```
w=Word.includes(:sample_sentences).where(Words: {id: 48}).where(sample_sentences: {list_id: 6})[0]
```

This works great if the word has an example sentence in the associated list. It **does not** work if the word has NO example sentence in the list. It returns no records.

The documentation [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and countless questions on Stack Overflow tell me that the resulting sql uses a left outer join to get the data. I believe my issue is the result of the additional WHERE on the sample_sentences table which seems to eliminate the possibility of getting back a word from the query with no sample sentences.

This is indeed borne out.. if I drop the additional where on the sample_sentences table, I get records back regardless of whether or not the word has an associated sample sentence. The problem is, I also get back sample sentences in which I am not interested.

Development database engine is SQL Lite. Production will be MySQL.

So.. I'm not sure what the best thing to do would be. Thoughts?

Comment: If I am reading your request correctly `Using eager loading, I would like to grab all words in a particular list and the sample sentences for that word for that particular list.`. It appears that you want all words regardless of whether they have comments. Try this: `Word.includes(:sample_sentences, :lists).where(lists: {id: #List id })`. This will include the sample sentences if they exist and you can test with an `empty?`.

Comment: @nikkon226 - this is great. Exactly what I needed. Thank you. Please post as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your request correctly `Using eager loading, I would like to grab all words in a particular list and the sample sentences for that word for that particular list.`. It appears that you want all words regardless of whether they have comments. Try this: `Word.includes(:sample_sentences, :lists).where(lists: {id: #List id })`. This will include the sample sentences if they exist and you can test with an `empty?`.